# How to use Flask Python in github actions to serve a web app?

Tags: python, html, flask, github-actions, github-pages

I have decided to use github action to display my web page and format it using Python Flask, but I can't get it to work... everything works fine, there are no errors and flask stays listening on the production port (0.0.0.0), but it seems that it doesn't listen to anything, I go to the url of the github page that I made and nothing, as if it wasn't listening to anything or sending requests.
Here is my YML code:

```
name: page
run-name: ${{ github.actor }} is testing out GitHub Actions 
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
permissions:
  contents: "write"
jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: production
    steps:
      - name: Installing dependencies
        run: python -m pip install Flask
      - run: echo "Iniciando..."
      - name: Check out repository code
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - run: echo "Creando servidor..."
      - name: Init server
        run: python "${{ github.workspace }}/server.py"
```

Here is my Python code:

```
from flask import Flask, request, Blueprint, render_template;
app = Flask(__name__);
DEBUG=False;
#Registramos una nueva url
media_pt=Blueprint("media", __name__, static_folder="./media", static_url_path="/media");
app.register_blueprint(media_pt);

media_pt=Blueprint("static", __name__, static_folder="./static", static_url_path="/static");
app.register_blueprint(media_pt);

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html");
@app.route("/ok")
def is_of():
    return "is okk";
if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0",debug=DEBUG)
```

At first, regardless of the fact that the github page gave me a 404 error, now that I configure the root of the project it only returns the readme file (for not getting the index.html (I placed it in the template folder))

Comment: 1. GitHub Actions is a CI/CD service that each run gives you a certain amount of time to build the artifacts. 2. GitHub Pages only allows static files to be served. So in no way those two support your attempt to host a Flask web app. You usually have to pay for the right hosting platform.

Comment: @LexLi Ha, since they use node.js I thought the github action was an attempt to provide a free server. Instead of jumping straight to reading the doc, you should read what it is first. Thank you.

Comment: @lexli mind turning that into an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Copied from the comment.

1. GitHub Actions is a CI/CD service that each run gives you a certain amount of time to build the artifacts.
2. GitHub Pages only allows static files to be served.

So in no way those two support your attempt to host a Flask web app.

To resolve this, you usually have to pay for the right hosting platform.